# How to integrate $\int e^{xe^{x}} \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

Is it possible to integrate the following function analytically? I've been trying integration by parts, but it doesn't work.

$$ \int  e^{xe^{x}} \mathrm{d}x $$

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your problem  is still worse than the sophomore's dream $\int x^x \,dx$. No hope (as Rbert Israel answered).

Answer (score 4):

There is no  elementary antiderivative here.  That can be proved using the Risch algorithm.